# Data normalisation for presenting to neural network

Tags: neural-network, normalization

I'm experimenting with neural networks and as an introduction I'm doing the popular stock market prediction method; feed in price and volumes in order to predict the future price. I need to normalise my data before presenting it to the network, but I'm unsure as to the methodology...

Each stock has a closing price and volume figure for each trading day; do I normalise the price data across the prices of all stocks for each day, or do I normalise it against the previous prices for that one stock?

I.e. I'm presenting StockA to the NN, do I normalise the price data against the previous prices of StockA, or do I normalise it with the price of StockA, B, C, D... for the date that's being presented?

Comment: You might like that - https://youtu.be/EZBUDG12Nr0?t=51m42s

Answer (score 0):

> In my opinion you should be treating this issue as a **hyperparameter**,
>   will say: Try both and do what works best.

In the end this comes down to what the Information in the stocks are like, and how many different (quantity, characteristics) stock data you have.

1. If you normalize over each single stock you'll probably get a better generalization, especially if you only have few data available.
2. However if you normalize over the whole stock data, you still keep the overall information of the whole dataset in each stock dataset (e.g. Magnitude of the stockprice) - which might help your model, since more expensive stocks might behave different from less expensive once.